# What exactly triggers ng-change?

Tags: angularjs

My code has this HTML snippet:

```
<div ng-repeat="wf in wos.word.wordForms">
     {{ wf.statusId }}
     <textarea ng-change="wf.statusId = 2"
               ng-model="wf.definition">
     </textarea>
     ...
     ...
```

When I change something in the textarea the wf.statusId becomes 2 as expected

Now I issue a save. It sends the current wf contents to the server. When I get back data from the server I copy it back into wf.

The data is populated correctly but even though the server returns a statusId of 3 I still see the HTML showing 2.

```
(response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IWordForm>): any => {
   wf = angular.copy(response.data);
},
```

> response.data.statusId = 3

When I look at the page I see the statusId is set to **2**

Is this expected behavior? If so is there any way that I can make it so that the ng-change does not set the value to 2 when I get data from the server? All I want is for it to change the value to 2 when I am doing a user input.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is happening because the `ng-change` event is being triggered when you update the value of wf. What about adding a timeout after `wf = angular.copy(response.data);` and then change `wf.statusId` to 2?

The code would be:

```
(response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IWordForm>): any => {
    wf = angular.copy(response.data);
    $timeout(function() {
        wf.statusId = 2;
    }, 1);
},
```

Try it and let me know if it works, I am not sure at all but it may work.

If you don't know how $timeout works, take a look at [$timeout Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: After using the timeout the value is still not set correctly.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the statuses. Moreover, why are you copying the value returned from the server? Is it different from the one sent?